# Unix domain socket stops working after exactly 219264 bytes

Tags: python, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I'm trying to receive several megabytes of data using a Unix domain socket. My problem is the received data always cuts off at 219,264 bytes. After receiving that amount, I can keep sending, however I cannot receive anything afterwards until I completely reset the connection. My code&minimal examples(given that the socket regularly gets sent data to) is below.

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(f"{socketpath}")
data = b""
while True:
    received = s.recv(1024)
    data += received
    print("Received some data")
```

```
while True:
    sock.send(b"{a JSON-RPC string}")
```

Server side is `go-ethereum`. There is no exception with receiving(simply a hang upon calling `recv`), with sending an `in s.send(...) OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` gets thrown once 219264 bytes are sent in total. Also, once I begin getting `Broken pipe`, `recv` begins to respond but always returns an empty result (`b''`).

*Seems to be happening with 36544 bytes as well now. Completely randomly one of the two.

Comment: You missed a `f` for the f-string at line 2 (`s.connect(f"{socketpath}"`)

Comment: What is at offset 219,264 of the data?

Comment: [mcve] please. You also need to show the sending side. Further, quote the full error including the backtrace.

Comment: At offset 219,264 there's pretty much nothing interesting, just a JSON string that cuts off there. / Edited to include those.